# Table view cell Editor: Unable to call commitEdit in textbox focus listener

Tags: javafx-2, focuslistener, treetablecelleditor

I created a table view with the cell editor using javafx2. To edit cell I created a textbox and created focus listener to find the changes in the cell. I called the CommitEdit() method to update the changes in table view but the table not get updated, but in SetOnKeyReleased() it is working?

The listener code I used for commiting the table cell:

```
textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

          @Override
          public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
              if(!newValue){
                    commitEdit();
                }
          }
      });
```

Comment: Have you followed the Oracle's table view tutorial? Have you put debug point in the listener?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes I followed the the Oracle's table view guide... I checked the listener in debug mode but i can't find any problem. CommitEdit method invoked by listener but table not get update..

Comment: Well then compare the tutorial's code with yours. Or post mcve.